# Python Scrapy scrape all the div in a particular div and get links from those each div

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I am **scraping** a website which has a list or collection of div in a particular div. So I am trying to get the links from each of this div. Do I need to iterate over it?

```
<div class="a">
    <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div>
    <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div>
    <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div>
    <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div>
    <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div>
    <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div>
    <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div>
</div>
```

So how can I extract second  href or link from each div.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you need?, all `href` from the second element of the `divs`s under `class = "b"`? If you can provide an output example would be great

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `response.xpath('//div[@class="a"]/div/div[2]/a')`. It will give you second `div` of `div.b` and then extract link `a` from it.

You can add some text to required `a`, so we would understand you more clear.

Comment: It will give the link only for the second div element but how can I get link of all div inside the div of class "a".

Comment: in this case just try css selector `response.css("div.a div.b a").extract()`, it will give you all the links.

Comment: Or if you prefer xpath, you can use `response.xpath('//div[@class="a"]/div[@class="b"]//a')`

Answer (score 0):

A more compact option is just to use `.css`, check it out:

```
In [12]: from parsel import Selector                                                                                                                                                                                

In [13]: text = '''<div class="a"> 
    ...:     <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div> 
    ...:     <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div> 
    ...:     <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div> 
    ...:     <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div> 
    ...:     <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div> 
    ...:     <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div> 
    ...:     <div class = "b"><div><a></a></div><div><a></a></div></div> 
    ...: </div>'''                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [14]: response = Selector(text)                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [15]: response.css('.a a').extract()                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[15]: 
['<a></a>',
 '<a></a>',
 '<a></a>',
 '<a></a>',
 '<a></a>',
 '<a></a>',
 '<a></a>',
 '<a></a>',
 '<a></a>',
 '<a></a>',
 '<a></a>',
 '<a></a>',
 '<a></a>',
 '<a></a>']
```

`.a` is a compact way to specify a tag-class.